# Push object into array without key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, vue.js

I want to push my object without a key in my javascript array. Right now the issue is I psuh my object in the array, but I add extra key 0,1,2 ... I don't want that key. Is there any solution for that? Here I add the code that I implemented.

```
let newArr = [];
let myId = data['id'];
var key = myId;
var obj = {};
myobj[key] = {
  data: "testdata"
};
newArr.push(myobj);
```

The above code generates output like below. I don't want that 0 key in my array

```
0: { 
    260: {
        data: 'testdata'
    },
}
```

Comment: that is an index that's automatically generated by javascript, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Then how do you retrieve the value from array? :|, and what sort of output you need?

Comment: Change var obj = {}; into var myobj = {} and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're wanting, but I expect you don't want to be using an array here at all? You just want a single object that contains all of your key-value pairs?

e.g. something like this:

```js
const data = { id: 1234 };

let myId = data['id'];
var key = myId;
var myobj = {};
myobj[key] = {
  data: "testdata"
};

console.log(myobj);

// You can then add more data
myobj[2345] = {
  data: "more test data"
};

console.log(myobj);

// Example Property Access
console.log(myobj[2345])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
newArr.push(...myobj);
```